# Unable to click a date in calendar as the link is continuously changing

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath, selenium-ide, mobiscroll

I'm trying to select the day in a calendar but can't because everytime i create a new workspace (new page in our UI) the Xpath changes.

Xpath

```
//div[@id='mobiscroll1486619404547']/div[2]/div/div/div/div[6]/div/div
```

Is there anyway for me to click it by class?

```
<div class="dw-cal-day-fg">1</div>
```

Edit

Selenium Script

```
<!--Set year to 2016-->
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>//div[@id='mobiCalendarId_dw_pnl_0']/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<!--set day to 1st-->
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//div[@id='mobiscroll1486619404547']/div[2]/div/div/div/div[6]/div/div</td>
    <td></td>
```

Code from the page

```
<div role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Friday, January 1 " data-day="5" data-full="2016-0-1" class="dw-cal-day  dw-cal-day-first dw-cal-day-v dwb-e dwb-nhl dw-sel" aria-selected="true">
<div class="dw-i  ">
<div class="dw-cal-day-fg">1</div>
<div class="dw-cal-day-frame"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us code and the website.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code but i am unable to link to the site as it is a private portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, using class attribute of `div` tag with `[3]` Here, indicates index number `[3]` as particular day.

For example, In below xpath I have use index number as `[3]`, so this xpath will find the third day inside your html.

```
//div[@class='dw-cal-day-fg'][3]
```

Comment: Thanks '//div[@class='dw-cal-day-fg']' worked to select a day but not the one i want. Its a start :)

I was trying to select the 1st so i can verify the date selector works but the 31st works just as well i guess

Comment: Which day you want to select? according to your question like this `<div class="dw-cal-day-fg">1</div>` i have provided you my answer as above.

Comment: Apologies! I would like to select the 1st day of the month. The div increases the number for the day `<div class="dw-cal-day-fg">1</div>` for the 1st `<div class="dw-cal-day-fg">2</div>` for the 2nd.. and so on

Comment: Use `indexing` in xpath like this way. `//div[@class='dw-cal-day-fg'][3]` will click on the third day.. if you want to click on some another day as for example `23` then pass indexing as `23` at the end of the xpath. I have update my answer as well.